# Нижние блоки лезут под фиксированную шапку

Tags: html, css

Сделал шапку сайта фиксированной, после этого блоки что под ней были, тупо залезли под нее, и шапка закрывает постоянно часть нижних блоков, даже если смотреть на нее с самого верхнего скрола страницы, помогите. или подскажите что сделать что бы нижние блоки скрывались только при прокруте страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Если шапку сделали фиксированной - то соответственно весь сайт поднялся вверх на высоту шапки.
Нужно сделать отступ сверху равен равен высоте высоты шапки.

Если шапка 50px высотой - сделать отступ от верха страницы 50px + зазор.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 с отступом в высоту шапки:

```css
header {
  height: 70px;     /* Высота шапки */
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
}

body {
  padding-top: 70px;  /* Отступ = высоте шапки */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <header>

  </header>
  
  <main>
    
  </main>
```

Вариант 2 с заглушкой под шапку:

```css
header {
  height: 70px;     /* Высота шапки */
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sub-header {
  height: 70px;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="sub-header"></div>
  <header>

  </header>
  
  <main>
    
  </main>
```